# A struct in Rust that contains two Vecs of sub-structs. One of the struct has a reference to the other one to make a link. How do i satisfy the BC?

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

Here is a made up example that reproduce the issue:

```
struct Metro<'a> {
    stations: Vec<Station<'a>>,
    monuments: Vec<Monument>
}

struct Station<'a> {
    name: String,
    closest_monument: Option<&'a Monument>
}

struct Monument {
    monument_name: String
}

impl <'a> Metro<'a> {
    pub fn stations_monument_assigning(&'a mut self){
        // in real life do some check to pick the best monument instead of first one
        self.stations[0].closest_monument = self.monuments.get(0);
    }

    pub fn new_network(stations: Vec<Station<'a>>, monuments: Vec<Monument>) -> Self {
        let mut metro = Metro { stations, monuments };
        metro.stations_monument_assigning();
        metro
    }
}
```

Here the compiler Error:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `metro`
  --> src/lib.rs:24:9
   |
23 |         metro.stations_monument_assigning();
   |         ----------------------------------- `metro` is borrowed here
24 |         metro
   |         ^^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

error[E0505]: cannot move out of `metro` because it is borrowed
  --> src/lib.rs:24:9
   |
15 | impl <'a> Metro<'a> {
   |       -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
22 |         let mut metro = Metro { stations, monuments };
   |             --------- binding `metro` declared here
23 |         metro.stations_monument_assigning();
   |         ----------------------------------- borrow of `metro` occurs here
24 |         metro
   |         ^^^^^
   |         |
   |         move out of `metro` occurs here
   |         returning this value requires that `metro` is borrowed for `'a`

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0505, E0515.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0505`.
error: could not compile `playground` (lib) due to 2 previous errors
```

It seems like the borrow checker does not understand that the station is referencing some data owned by the same struct, and makes it impossible the lose the data.

I tried playing with lifetime, ownership but nothing fancy.
I don't really know what to look for.